# Как собрать массив промисов?

Tags: javascript

Насколько мне известно - промис начинает работать когда на него кто-то подписывается, например через `await` или `then`.

Почему, когда я собираю массив промисов, они начинают работать даже если я не вызываю `promise all`?

Код:

```
const a = [1,2]

const aa = async (a) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
    return 131;
}

const messages = a.map((item) => {
    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        let a = await aa(item)
        console.log(a);
        resolve(a)
    })
    return promise;

});

console.log(messages);

//Promise.all(messages)
```

Ожидаемое поведение:

`console.log(a)` никогда не отработает.

Фактическое поведение:

Я вижу `console.log`

Comment: "Насколько мне известно" - откуда такие странные идеи?

Comment: @Yaant, так... А можно, пожалуйста, ликбез - когда начинает работу промис? Мои предположения ложны, верно?

Comment: Когда вы пишите `new Promise(func)` функция `func` вызывается сразу. Что она будет делать и когда она вызовет `resolve` или `reject` это уже её дело.